# node debugger on windows

Tags: node.js, windows, debugging, virtual-machine

It has been six months since I have started developing applications with nodejs. My current project is a script (no html to open in any browser, just javascripts) resides on a linux VM. I cannot run it locally because I have a windows machine and one of the node modules cannot be run on windows.

The thing that I don't like is that for debugging I need to put console.log everywhere in the code, then run my js file using the command node myfile.js to inspect variables. OR I need to put debugger everywhere and use node debug.

I tried using Webstorm application to debug it in a way that is more similar to what I used to do in eclipse or .net environment, however I figured out that opening the remote code locally by mounting my VM to my local machine and debugging it with the local ndoe.js in webstorm is not possible, or at least I couldn't do it so far.

So my question is if there is any way that I can debug my node project which resides and is run on a linux VM, in any way rather than putting console.log or debugger around the code. Something similar to eclipse or .net environment.

Comment: you can use visual studio code in your linux vm

Comment: which module doesn't run in windows? have you tried docker instead of a vm?

Comment: @jack.the.ripper how docker could be different? If we use docker we will set up an image that is pretty similar to the linux environment I have on the VM. the module is a google api to send requests to DFP.

Comment: @jack.the.ripper I don't get your point by "visual studio code in your linux vm". I don't have the power to choose the programming language. It has to  be nodejs.

Comment: you can use visual studio code to debug node.js in you Linux VM, regarding docker is similar to a vm but it's more lightweight because you'll program locally but using linux environment by using a docker container, btw I'm curious about the library that you can't run on linux

Comment: You can use node-inspector which is a nodejs debugger that hooks into node and offers an interface in Chrome.  I use it similarly to the regular client-side Javascript debugger in Chrome (as it has a similar interface).  Then, you can set breakpoints, inspect variables, etc... just like real debugging (because it is real debugging).

Comment: @jack.the.rippermany thanks, I didn't knwo about visual studio, that would be an interesting research since I really like visual studio env. We made a library similar to this: https://github.com/ShinyAds/node-google-dfp, we use var google = require('googleapis') to use this service: https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-publishers/docs/rel_notes

Comment: @jfriend00 many thanks, I tried to use that, but I got "No browser matching [chrome,chromium,opera] found in the system!" error, which I couldn't solve that yet.